# Evaluate the Weiner index of the star $K_1,_{n-1}$

Tags: graph-theory

Evaluate the Weiner index of the star $K_1,_{n-1}$ and show that this is the only tree on $n$ vertices with the minimum Weiner index.

I need some reference about Weiner index, my teacher did not explain completely. Do you have any solution for my problem as I mention above ?

Answer (score 1):

It's the [*Wiener index*](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WienerIndex.html); it's the sum of the distances between all pairs of vertices. For $K_{1,n-1}$, therefore, it's $$n-1+2\binom{n-1}2=n-1+(n-1)(n-2)=(n-1)^2\;.$$

Here the $n-1$ term accounts for the distances from the centre to the $n-1$ points, and the term with the binomial coefficient accounts for the distances between distinct points of the star.

For a tree on $n$ vertices you'll have $n-1$ edges, each corresponding to a pair of vertices one unit apart. How many other pairs of vertices are there? What's the minimum distance between any two of them?

Comment: M.Scott : is it true the minimum distance between any two of them is $\frac {n(n-1)}2$

Comment: @user273952: No, once you've accounted for the pairs that are neighbors, any other pairs must be at least two units apart.

Comment: So what is the minimum distance between any two of them ?

Comment: @user273952: I just said: they must be at least two units apart.

Answer (score 0):

It is discussed in my favorite Graph Theory book, Introduction to Graph Theory (2nd Edition) by Douglas B. West.

Here is a problem I like, which you may like to solve:

[image]

Comment: I like if you solve this problem, Can you find a tree T on $n$ vertices and a vertex $v \in V(T)$ so that $\sum_{u \in V(T)} d(u,v) \le \binom n2$. This problem still about the Wiener index, sorry if this problem not in your list. Thanks

Comment: Yes. Assume $n\geq 2$.  Take the star on $n$ vertices and let $v$ be the center vertex. Then $\sum d(u,v)=n-1\leq \frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ equals $n$ choose $2$.